# What do I need to change im my App to migrate Restful_Authentication to Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration, devise, restful-authentication

I found a tutorial here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Migrate-from-restful_authentication-to-Devise-, however it seems like it is missing pieces of what to do, for example the restful_authentication plugin is still there...how do I remove it?  Then how does Devise know what to get for my App...I've tried it but it just keeps breaking my App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Erase everything in the user.rb controller (or your controller)
2. Make Sure all of Restful_Authenication is gone (there is quite a bit of includes that may be presnet)
3. Make sure devise_for :users is present in the routes.rb file
4. Look for method errors and replace them back in the User.rb controller.

Think that fixed it.